# How to calculate how much weak acid would dissociate in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, ph, buffer

So I know water has a pH of 7. If we add 0.1 mol of a strong acid inside 1 liter of water, it WILL fully dissociate into 0.1 mol of A- and 0.1 mol of H+ thus making the pH of the solution 1.

But what if we add 0.1 mol of a weak acid HA, let's say acetic acid, in 1 liter of water? How would I know how much of this acid would dissociate in water and what would be the pH of the solution?

**Using the found information that only 1% of the acid would dissociate**, the pH of solution would be 2. Knowing that the pKa of acetic acid is 4.75, I calculated using Henderson-Hasselback that only 1% of acetic acid would be deprotonated.

But, to calculate the pH, firstly I needed to know how much of it dissociated. So how can I know in first place how much of a weak acid would dissociate in water?

Comment: The amount dissociated and the pH are one and the same quantity. In other words the $\ce{H+}$ cations come from the dissociation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be given $K_\mathrm{a}$ of the weak acid. If you know it, you can set up the expression for $K_\mathrm{a}$:

$$\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}= K_\mathrm{a}$$

Let $x$ be the amount of the weak acid dissociate at equilibrium. Thus, at equilibrium, $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{A-}] = x$
and $[\ce{HA}]$ will be its initial concentration minus $x$. This can be derived from an ICE table as well. The equilibrium expression then becomes:

$$\frac{x^2}{[\ce{HA}]_i-x}= K_\mathrm{a}$$

We can assume $[\ce{HA}]_i-x = [\ce{HA}]_i$ because $x$ would be quite small compared to $[\ce{HA}]_i$ since it is a weak acid. Then you get the following expression:

$$\frac{x^2}{[\ce{HA}]_i} \approx K_\mathrm{a}$$

You can then solve for $x$, which would be how much of the weak acid dissociates given the $K_{a}$

One important thing to note is that this approximation will not work well with acids that have a relatively high Ka or there is a low initial concentration. So you should check that $$[HA]_i >> [H^+] >> [OH^-]$$ If not, you cannot simplify the expression and would instead have to solve it as a quadratic.

Comment: I would add in a compact way there is assumption of this simplification that $c_0 \gg [\ce{H+}] \gg [\ce{OH-}]$. So generally, after getting pH, it is good to check if these conditions are met.

Comment: @M.L: Your $x$ can't be an integer. So, I change it accordingly. I'd like you to check it that you agree or not. I upvoted regardless.

Comment: Thanks. x is generally not supposed to be an integer. It is just how much the concentration of the weak acid changes at equilibrium based on the Ka given (If this is what you meant). As for the first comment, I agree that it is important to check that because sometimes Ka might be large enough for the approximation to be inaccurate. I will make this correction.